# No consigo hacer TAGs en GitLab

Tags: pipeline, yaml, gitlab-ci, tags

Llevo bastante tiempo intentando hacer un simple tag en un commit (aviso de que soy novato extremo en esto), y no consigo nada. Siempre me dice problema de permisos, pero ya he hecho todo lo que he encontrado de configurar los datos de acceso a mi repositorio, incluso me he creado un Token y nada, siempre me dice:

**remote: You are not allowed to upload code.**

Esta es la última configuración que he puesto en mi .yml:

```
- git add .
- git commit -m "Nuevo commit"
- git tag -a v1.0.6 -m "Versión 1.0.6"
- git push --follow-tags origin main
- git push --tags
```

He intentado configurar los permisos en mi PC haciendo esto a través de PowerShell y diferentes cosas más pero no consigo hacer que funcione:

git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.git-credentials'
echo "https://tu_usuario:${tu_token}@gitlab.com" > ~/.git-credentials

He vuelto a clonar el repositorio, he intentando directamente desde el repositorio...,nada, hasta ahora no consigo poner un TAG a un commit.

Sabrían por favor qué puedo hacer? a lo mejor es una tontería, pero es que como me estoy iniciando en esto pues no tengo mucha idea.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No tienes permisos para subir los cambios. El administrador del repositorio debe permitirte crear nuevas ramas y crear tags

Comment: Pero es que no puede ser eso, no? porque si yo por ejemplo creo una carpeta en mi Visual Studio Code y le hago push, me aparece en el repositorio. El problema con los push los tengo siempre cuando los pongo en el yaml. Eso puede ser posible? Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Creo que ya se entiende un poco mejor. Cómo corre ese Yaml? Quién lo usa, qué programa?

Comment: Bueno, no sé si entiendo bien la pregunta porque soy novato extremo en esto, pero voy a intentar comentar lo que me preguntas. El yaml lo tengo en un proyecto de .Net, el runner es mi propio pc con Windows10 y en este momento debido a diversos problemas que me voy encontrando, estoy intentando a ver si soy capaz de aprender lo que es un Docker y pasarlo todo por ahí. Muchas gracias por responder.